# AutoMapper many to many relationship into collection

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to map entities into a collection through a many to many table using AutoMapper.

My domain model (Entity Framework) looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public IList<UserCompany> UserCompanies { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserCompany
{
    public int UserCompanyID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map to a class that looks like this:

```
public class CompanyDTO
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserDTO
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<CompanyDTO> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

My current mapping configuration looks like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDTO>(); //works no problem

Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
    .ForMember( dto => dto.Companies,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(x => Mapper.Map<IList<Company>, IList<CompanyDTO>>(x.UserCompanies.Select( y => y.Company ).ToList())));
```

Asserting that the configuration is valid returns true, but when I try to actually map a User to a UserDTO, I get: Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match.

If I use AfterMap and manually move over each Company into the Companies list, it will work, but it seems like I should be able to handle this within create map.

In my query to get a single user from the DB I am including the UserCompany.Company navigation property and I can quickwatch and see that there is being returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to have the explicit map in your mapping configuration. You should be able to do something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Companies, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UserCompanies));
```

You'll also need to define a mapping for UserCompany:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserCompany, CompanyDTO>();
```

Note that you don't have a CompanyDTO class in your examples so I can't determine the actual mapping configuration.

**Update**

I presume there is a reason why you need an IList in your User entity rather than simply an IList. Given that, I believe you need a custom resolver: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers

**Update 2**

I'm glad you have it sorted. For completeness, heres the example should you decide to use a custom ValueResolver with the classes above.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Companies, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CompanyResolver>());
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Where CompanyResolver is something like

```
public class CompanyResolver : ValueResolver<User, IList<CompanyDTO>>
{
    protected override IList<CompanyDTO> ResolveCore(User source)
    {
        return source.UserCompanies
            .Select(userCompany =>
                    Mapper.Map<Company, CompanyDTO>(companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyID == userCompany.CompanyID)))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the result was the same.  UserCompany is an entity that joins User and Company, so in order to map UserCompany to Company I had to explicitly map each field, i.e.
    Mapper.CreateMap<UserCompany, CompanyDTO>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Company.Name);

In addition to that tried removing my line mapping the IList of Company objects and I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: Additionally tried switching my MapTo to this: .ForMember(dto => dto.Companies, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UserCompanies)), same error.

Comment: Mighty, I figured it out.  I didn't think it was worth mentioning, but the Dto objects I was mapping to were actually interface types.  The error was happening when AutoMapper was trying to create a proxy object for it.  My original mapping code worked fine, with the addition of this line to the mapping setup.

    .ConstructUsing((Func<ResolutionContext, UserDTO>)(x => new UserDTO()))

Thanks for your help!