# Automapper with composite DTO (many-to-many)

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many, entity-framework-6, automapper

Not having more than a month's worth experience with EF and Automapper, I'm really battling to get the following done:

I've got 3 DB entities as follow: (unnecessary fields remove for simplicity)
[image: 3 Entities as per DB Design]

Within my project i have these entities pulled in through EF, and I created 2 DTO classes as follow:

```
[DataContract]
public class StoreDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int StoreID {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string StoreName{get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public List<CategoryDTO> Categories {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class CategoryDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int CategoryID {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string CategoryName{get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public List<StoreDTO> Stores{get; set;}
}
```

I'm using automapper to try and map the two classes but I'm really battling to get the composite relationship going.

My map creation looks something like this now (after numerous tries):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Store, StoreDTO>(); // Not performing the category list mapping yet here

// This is where I attemped the mapping for a store list in each category:
// x.Store_StoreCategory = StoreCategory as composite entity above
Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Stores,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(x => Mapper.Map<List<Store>, List<StoreDTO>>(x.Store_StoreCategory.Select(y => y.Store).ToList())));
```

This isn't working though. I read a few articles and the latest i came across is this one by Jimmy Bogard himself:
[Avoid many-to-many mappings in ORMs](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/)

He suggests creating the composite DTO as well and work from there which seems like a good way to go but I need help with the mapping as I'm a TSQL guy, not yet a LINQ guy with automapper and DTO capabilities...

Other articles I tried were the following but with my lack of knowledge on Automapper and EF, I fear I might be missing the point somewhere as these articles don't refer to the composite DTO as suggested by Jimmy Bogard:

[AutoMapper many to many relationship into collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782948/automapper-many-to-many-relationship-into-collection)

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers

[Many-to-many to DTOs using Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441321/many-to-many-to-dtos-using-automapper)

Would really appreciate some insight!

Comment: What isn't working about the code you posted?

Comment: To get the categories for each store is easy as there's 9/10 times only 1 category per store. The opposite where a category could have multiple stores becomes an issue and times-out when fired. I fear that the code I used worked with the store -> category link because of data simplicity (i.e. 1-1 relationship), but it obviously isn't efficient enough for 1-many? Given I'm not an expert with either EF, Automapper or LINQ I'm battling to see where I'm going wrong..